# Newtcolorbox and foreach

Tags: macros, tcolorbox, foreach

I have defined 2 Boxes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{one}{}
\newtcolorbox{two}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{one}
The new command works fine
\end{one}

\begin{two}
The new command works fine
\end{two}

\end{document}
```

But with `\foreach` result error:

```
\foreach \i in {one,two}{
\newtcolorbox{\i}{}
}
```

**Approach:**

```
\foreach \i in {one,two}{
\expandafter\newtcolorbox{\csname\i\endcsname}{ }}
```

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Every cycle in a `\foreach` loop is done inside a group, so the `\newtcolorbox` declaration is lost as soon as the group ends.

You may appreciate a general loop that doesn't need groups:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\lforeach}{mm}
 {% #1 = list, #2 = template
  \cs_set:Nn \__lforeach_temp:n { #2 }
  \clist_map_function:nN { #1 } \__lforeach_temp:n
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\lforeach{one,two}{\newtcolorbox{#1}{}}

\begin{document}

\begin{one}
The new command works fine
\end{one}

\begin{two}
The new command works fine
\end{two}

\end{document}
```

If you're running LaTeX with a release date prior to 2020-10-01, you also need `\usepackage{xparse}`.

The idea is the same as with `\foreach`, but you don't need to use a scratch macro  such as `\i` to denote the current item (which is the main reason why `\foreach` uses grouping), using instead `#1`.

You can use this loop in various contexts.

Comment: Notice that the `/.list` key handler does not group the cycles either (as I wrote clearly in my post), **and** it understands things like `something/.list={1,3,...,11}`, which this construction does not.

Comment: Also, the `/.list` hander works right out of the box, there is absolutely no need to add a command of the above type unless one is keen in duplicating the repertoire unnecessarily.

Comment: @user238301 I don't understand the point of your comments. I just presented a different solution that can be used in several situations. Others may be good in different ones.

Comment: Thank you egreg for your answer, it works fine with auto counter.

Answer (score 5):

`\foreach` creates groups and I am not sure what the `\csname...\endcsname` is for, but the following works.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\pgfkeys{new tcolorbox/.code=\newtcolorbox{#1}{},
new tcolorbox/.list={one,two}}

\begin{document}

\begin{one} The new command works fine \end{one}

\begin{two} The new command works fine \end{two}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you user238301 for your solution, it works fine.

Comment: @felipeuni Consider accepting the answer if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

An approach using only `\expandafter`s.  It helps to define `\addto` and `\xaddto`.  Here, the `\foreach` just strings together the future commands into the global `\tmp`, which is executed after the group is exited.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\gdef\expandafter#1\expandafter{\tmp#2}}
\def\xaddto#1#2{\expandafter\addto\expandafter#1\expandafter{#2}}
\def\tmp{}
\foreach \i in {one,two}{
  \addto\tmp{\newtcolorbox}
  \xaddto\tmp{\expandafter{\i}{}}
}\tmp
\begin{document}

\begin{one}
The new command works fine
\end{one}

\begin{two}
The new command works fine
\end{two}

\end{document}
```